# All links in a series of hash references show visited when one is clicked

Tags: html, css, anchor

My a:link and a:visited code in CSS isn't working. I'm not sure why and it's a bit weird

Also, it's actually doing the opposite of what I want. Before visiting, the link is violet and after it's the same.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  font-family: century gothic;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  color: black;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a:link {
  color: black;
}
a:visited {
  color: blueviolet;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
#image1,
#image2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  width: 70%;
}
p {
  text-align-last: center;
  font-family: helvetica, lucida grande, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Event</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<p>Your Home Show Your Vision</p>

<img src="p.d.jpg" alt="Your Perspective" id="image1" />

<img src="e7179db2d394aab60672c37700e15612.jpg" alt="Your Perspective" id="image2" />



<footer>Copyright &copy 2017</footer>
```

Comment: This question makes no sense. Without JavaScript those links do nothing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The visited selector matches all elements whose `href` links are already visited.

You need to set different `href` values, like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="event.html">Event</a></li>
    <li><a href="galery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    font-family: century gothic;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul {
    color: black;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
    color:#000;
}
a:link {
    color: black;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
    color: blueviolet;
}
footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
}
#image1, #image2 {
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 70%;
}
p {
    text-align-last: center;
    font-family: helvetica, lucida grande, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="event.html">Event</a></li>
      <li><a href="galery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```